# The specified default EntityContainer name 'HanamiHotelEntities' could not be found in the mapping and metadata information

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just dont get it:

I have this program.cs

```
        static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MDIMain MdiMain = new MDIMain();
        frmLogin login = new frmLogin();

        login.ShowDialog();

        if (login.LoginOk)
        {
            Application.Run(MdiMain);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
```

Everything works fine there. My login and my MDIMain shows OK. The problem is that as soon as MDIMain shows up and I want to do anything y get this error.

> The specified default EntityContainer name 'HanamiHotelEntities' could not be found in the mapping and metadata information.
>   Parameter name: defaultContainerName

This is the section of the code wich shows the error

```
    public partial class HanamiHotelEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "name=HanamiHotelEntities";
    public const string ContainerName = "HanamiHotelEntities";

    #region Constructors

    public HanamiHotelEntities()
        : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
```

Whats confuses me is that I only get that error if I use the frmLogin first, but if I just show the MDIMain wiouth using the frmLogin everything works fine. Its like the app.config just stop woring for some reason...

By the way, I do have the connection string on my app.config.

Please, if anyone knows anything about whats happening here please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the context in the login procedure?

Comment: Can you post the code behind of mdimain?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when my connection string had a copy paste problem - metadata referencing csdl, ssdl, msl of another connection string...